# svg element inside object will not trigger css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an svg loaded into an object tag like this

`<object id="garageFile" type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/garage.svg"></object>`

Inside the garage.svg is a path

```
...
<g>
    <path id="gateRight" state="close" fill="#21100C" d="M1075.823,637.254l606.078,25.422l1.229-504.793l-610.07,2.066"/>
</g>
...
```

What I would like to do is to animate the path with the id gateRight. Therefore I created a css with the following content

```
 .gateRightOpenFast {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.gateRightOpenFast {
    -moz-transform: rotateX(74deg) rotateZ(-1deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(74deg) rotateZ(-1deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(74deg) rotateZ(-1deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(74deg) rotateZ(-1deg);
    transform: rotateX(74deg) rotateZ(-1deg);
}
```

To start the animation I run this javascript code

```
var garageObject = document.getElementById('garageFile');
var garageSvgDoc;

$('body').find('#garageFile').load("image/svg+xml", function() {
    garageSvgDoc = garageObject.contentDocument;

    $( garageSvgDoc ).find('#gateRight').attr('class', 'gateRightOpenFast');
}
```

My problem is that the animation wont work this way.

---

Asn an alternative I tried to add the svg directly in the html file and accesed it with following command

`$( '#gateRight' ).attr('class', 'gateRightOpenFast');`

and everything works fine.

---

Can someone explain me how to use the css animation with the svg loaded as an object?

Comment: How does th SVG file (garage.svg) know about the CSS?

Comment: It doesn't? I thought the object element knows the css file which has the content of the svg as its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the line

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
```

to your SVG file as the [first line in that file](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS). Take care to replace mystyle.css with the actual name of your CSS file.

If your SVG file doesn't know about your CSS file you can't use any animations contained in that CSS file.